# Cannot run prepared statement/function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How to get a row in a temp variable and process/use its fields?? 
See the begin section, I need to get account info, do some calculations, like I need to get value of Account.field1 - Account.Field2 in accountbalance method , how to do that?? 
    --this is statement

```
PREPARE get_account (varchar) AS
SELECT * FROM "Accounts" WHERE "AccountKey" = $1 LIMIT 1;

-- Try to run directly
select EXECUTE(get_account("A200"));


--Created a function and used statement. 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION accountbalance(VARCHAR) RETURNS REAL AS $$
    DECLARE
    AKey ALIAS FOR $1;  
    balance REAL;
    account RECORD;
BEGIN   
   account := EXECUTE(get_account("A200"));
   --Tried these too
   --account := EXECUTE get_account('A200');    
   --account := EXECUTE get_account("A200");    
   --I need to get account data here, process, How to get data to a declared variable, how user specific column, May be something like Accounts."Total".. 
   --I tried to run direct query here and get data to account, but no success so tried prepared statement. 
   --I will be doing complex calculations here, trying to return a column for test , not sure is it correct? 
RETURN account.Actual;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--Used function in sql

Select accountbalance('A200');
```

in both cases receive error like this.

ERROR:  column "A200" does not exist
LINE 1: select EXECUTE(get_account("A200"));
                                   ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "A200" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 28

Comment: double quotes are used for relations, not values

Comment: you don't execute prepared statement when you `select EXECUTE(get_account("A200"));` - you execute your function

Comment: I tried all options, select EXECUTE(get_account('A200')), and select EXECUTE(get_account(A200));

Comment: try `execute get_account ('a200');`

Comment: Well I am able to run this EXECUTE get_account('A200'); and it gets result set, But within function it gives syntex error HERE.

 account := EXECUTE get_account('A200');

Comment: this is completely different question. Your described problem was wrong way to run prepared statement and using column name instead of text string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need it? Any embedded SQL in PLpgSQL is implicitly prepared statement. Explicitly prepared statements are not supported in PLpgSQL. Maybe you want to use dynamic SQL - see `EXECUTE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

you don't execute [prepared statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) when you select EXECUTE(get_account("A200")); - you execute your function. Here's example of how to run prepared statements:

```
t=# PREPARE get_account (varchar) AS SELECT * FROM pg_tables where tablename = $1;
PREPARE
t=# execute get_account ('pg_statistic');
 schemaname |  tablename   | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers
------------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------
 pg_catalog | pg_statistic | postgres   |            | t          | f        | f
(1 row)
```

For you prepared stmt it would be

```
execute get_account ('a200');
```

Regarding using sql `EXECUTE` in plpgsql block (which has it's own `EXECUTE` - very different from sql one), please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/12708117/5315974

Comment: But this does not work within function accountbalance(), see my question,  
account := EXECUTE get_account('A200');